# Converting a Twos-complement number to its binary representation

Tags: javascript, floating-point, binary, numbers, twos-complement

I am doing some bitwise manipulation.

I am adding a 32 bit number to another 32 bit number with |= instead of += because I was thinking the number might be getting messed up when it converts to 32 bit (binary wasn't showing up right).

Basically, the number at the end of my operations is the two's complement interpretation of the bitwise manipulation i've performed. I think the original binary I was trying to get out of my operations is getting kicked out when it takes that two's complement number and converts it into the standard 64 bit float (when the operation is complete). As in, the binary stops being considered and it just tries to take the result, say -5, and make a 64 bit binary representation for that. But the bit representation of -5 in twos complement and the standard 64 bit number is quite different, obviously.

I only care about the binary, the number that it gets interpreted as is not an issue to me at the end of the day.

I just want to be sure my binary won't get kicked out. How can I preserve my binary in my operations without having to break out how I step into my binary string?

I don't really want to break my 32 bit numbers into 8-bit or 16-bit but is that the only way?

I'm still trying to understand what exactly goes on when javascript is doing its bitwise stuff, so I wouldn't be surprised if I've muddied an important detail.

Please help! I need to understand what is going on here and how to work around it.

Edit: in the debugger, after manipulation, the number gets displayed as the two's complement interpretation of my bits, which is confusing to me because i thought it converts back to a 64 bit number before ever returning the value to any user code.

I really didn't want to provide my code because I didn't want to have to get into the details of why I'm doing each little step, but basically i have the binary of an integer number of increment "counts" that is an argument to a binary string. sbs is an abbreviation for startBits, which is an array of the position of the first bit (MSB) from left to right (left being MSB). Basically, the start bit is the 1-based position that the first bit OCCUPIES (hence some weird -1's or +1's here or there) and the tot bits is the total number of bits that the arguemnt contains. If there are more than one elements in the startbit array (sbs) then the number of bits in each placement of bits to a startbit is just the total bits divided by the length of the startbit array. so if there are two elements in the startbit array and a tot bit of 4 then the 2 MSB bits of the "counts" value will be placed at sbs[0] and the 2 LSB bits at sbs[1]. Hopefully that is clear enough.

Here is my code:

```js
function getHexCode(thing){
    return parseInt(thing.hexCode.slice(0,8), 16);
  }

  function constructArglessBinaryString(thing){
    return getHexCode(thing);
  }
  
  function constructBinaryStringWithArgs(thing, counts){
    var bin = []
    bin.push(constructArglessBinaryString(thing));
    bin.push(0);
    let tbs = thing.args[0].totBits;
    let sbs = thing.args[0].startBits;
    let mask = (1 << tbs/sbs.length) - 1; // make mask a continguous length of 1 bits
    let i = 0;
    do{
      let a = counts & (mask << (tbs/sbs.length * i)); // & the mask with the counts at a sequential location along the counts total bits length
      let b = a >>> (tbs/sbs.length * i); // shift the result back before incorporating into binary string
      if (sbs[i] <= 32){
        var x = (b << (32 - sbs[i] - tbs/sbs.length + 1));
        bin[0] |= (b << (32 - sbs[i] - tbs/sbs.length + 1));        // place into binary string at respective sb location
      }
        else 
        bin[1] |= (b << (32 - (sbs[i]-32) - tbs/sbs.length + 1));   // case in which the arg bits go in the second 32 bits
      i++;
    }while(i<sbs.length)
    return bin;
  }
```

Comment: Please give some examples, and an [example] of what you tried. I have no idea what "my binary won't get kicked out" means, or how "binary wasn't showing up right". What are your inputs, what do you expect for output and why, what actually happens? Finally, JavaScript bitwise operations operate on 32-bit integers, or big integers, there is no support for 64-bit integers.

Comment: without your code it's hard to say what you may be doing wrong

Comment: Edited with code sample. x is being displayed as a two's complement interpretation of the manipulated binary

Comment: You are right, there is too much code (and we could ask "what does this do" the whole day), and it is not executable (we don't have `thing`, or `counts`), and I really don't want to go through it mentally, without knowing what result I should be expecting. Please re-read about [example]. I.e. isolate what is going wrong, and give the smallest piece of JavaScript that reproduces the problem. And I'm afraid I'll have to quote myself, as it had no effect the first time around: "What are your inputs, what do you expect for output and why, what actually happens?"

Comment: If you are asking about unexpected results in a bitwise operation, one line of code should suffice to demonstrate it (per operation that you are worried about). For example, "Why does `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`? I'm getting `0.30000000000000004` instead" demonstrates the problem with `+` and floating point.

Comment: The result of my operations is stored as a 2s comp number. That is fine. But when I say num.toString(2) I get a completely different binary representation, the raw number's binary instead of the 2s comp. I know that this is happening because when I make this binary string (10000011101000100001100000111000) it gets displayed as this number (-2086528968) but when i use toString(2) on that number I get (-1111100010111011110011111001000). How do I get the first string back? 
Link to a converter: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html      Put in this number:-2086528968

Comment: `((2 ** 32) - 2086528968).toString(2)`? (also, I saw this by pure luck - use `@Amadan` to make your response pop up a notification for me.)